# Skip list and modify a global index in python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am having an issue with last part of a code im creating. I am trying to, for example, make the list iterate to item 3 normally, but then check if the item is 3 and other condition (which doesn't matter right now), then change the index to iterate from example 10.

I made a lot of attempts but it doesn't seem to work.

```
li = [3, 8, 1, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6]
'''
HERE COMES OTHER CODE WHICH WORKS BASED ON THE ITERATION
'''
for i in range(0,len(li)):
    print(i)
    if i == 3: #along with other condition
        def g(li):
            global i
            i = li[9]
        g()
        print(i)
```

Maybe if it wasn´t clear here, what i am looking for is when 3 and the other condition reach the condition, then it skip to the index 9 to keep iterating the rest of the script from 9 which would be the new value.

Comment: Why are you defining a function calling just after defining it in each iteration? I dont think you need a global scope here as well

Comment: What is the expected outcome

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, and I'm struggling to, the OP wants a function to look at the first three entries in the list, and if another condition is also true, jump to the ninth entry and continue looking at the remainder of the list.

Comment: you could split the list in two and use them in the conditions. Assigning `i` any value won't make python jump iterations. In each iteration, on the loop scope, `i` variable will start with the the current range value. Assigning it means that you just changed local scope variable `i` value in current iteration

Answer (score 2):

I am sure I have not got your question right. But while loop should be preferred here

```
i=0
while i<len(li):
    if i == 3: #along with other condition
        i = li[9]
        print(i)
        continue
    i += 1
```

Comment: I don't believe setting i to the value in index 9 of the list and then continue counting from there was the goal, but who know... maybe it was, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do what you want is to set a flag if that condition is met and `continue` thru the skipped indices if that flag is true

```
li = [3, 8, 1, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6]
'''
HERE COMES OTHER CODE WHICH WORKS BASED ON THE ITERATION
'''
do_skip = False
for i in range(len(li)):

    if i == 3: #along with other condition
        do_skip = True

    # don't skip past a certain point
    if do_skip and i < 9:
        continue

    print(i)
```

Alternatively, you can use a while loop:

```
li = [3, 8, 1, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6]
'''
HERE COMES OTHER CODE WHICH WORKS BASED ON THE ITERATION
'''
i = 0
while i < len(li):

    if i == 3: #along with other condition
        i = 9

    print(i)

    # other loop operations go here

    i += 1
```

Comment: OP wants to jump to an index in the list li

Comment: Their code and question mismatch, so I went with their stated objective of "...keep iterating the rest of the script from 9..."

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it:

```
li = [3, 8, 1, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6]
flag = True # Conditional Flag
for x, i in enumerate(li):
  if x > 2 and not flag: break
  if 3 > x or x > 8: print(x, "has a value of", i)
```